# Contentful UI Extension Tutorial

Tags: contentful

I am trying to follow the [UI Extensions Tutorial](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/ui-extensions/managing-a-ui-extension/)

At time code 02:36 I run the `npm install && npm run login && npm run configure && npm run start` command.

Afterwards I get the error: `Cannot find module 'E:\Dev\Contentful\my-first-sidebar\node_modules\@contentful\contentful-extension-scripts\lib\index.js'`.

I have globally re-installed the CLI and re-run the install/start command but still same error. I have also searched my hard drive for the `contentful-extension-scripts\lib\` folder.

I see I have a contentful-extensions-scripts and contentful-extensions-scripts.cmd files and tried to run the `cmd` file but no use.

I am running on a Windows 10 box. Node version: 10.16.3​, Npm version: 6.9.0

#### UPDATE

I found the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/contentful/create-contentful-extension) for `contentful-extensions-scripts`, cloned it and copied over the folder but now I get the error: `Cannot find module 'parcel-bundler'` and I am out of my depth.

Comment: Are you running this in a Powershell window? The ampersands in that command will only work in a bash shell. You'll have to run `npm install`, `npm run login`, `npm run configure` and `npm run start` separately.

Comment: No, I’ve tried the Windows Console (CMD) and bash shell. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to package.json to fix it:

```
 "@contentful/contentful-extension-scripts": "^0.14.0".
```